# How to remove empty list from column?

Tags: python-3.x, string, pandas

I have a df that looks like this

```
list
[]
[8,8]
[0,9]
[]
```

This column has a dtype of `object`. How do I remove the `[]` from the column and replace with np.nan?

I have tried string replace but the brackets are not be

```
df.list = df.list.replace('"[]"','')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `astype(bool)`

```
df=df[df['list'].astype(bool)]
```

Comment: Perfect thank you!